# Prove a limit in two variables is $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

I have the limit

\begin{align}
\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(xy)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}
\end{align}

First thing I did is to use Taylor, so $$1-\cos(xy)=\frac{(xy)^2}{2} -\frac{(xy)^4}{4} + o((xy)^4)$$

Therefore the limit is $$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{1}{2} \frac{x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}$$

Now, $\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2} \leq 1$, therefore I have

$$\left|\frac{1}{2} \frac{x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}\right| \leq \left|\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right| \leq \frac{x^2}{|x|} = |x|$$

Since $|x| \rightarrow 0 $ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$, the limit is $0$, correct?

Answer (score 2):

It seems correct, to avoid Taylor we can use that

$$\frac{1-\cos(xy)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{1-\cos(xy)}{(xy)^2}\frac{(xy)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}$$

with $\frac{1-\cos(xy)}{(xy)^2} \to \frac12$ by standard limits.

For the conclusion by squeeze theorem, we should also consider a part the case $x=0$.

Comment: But then you have to compute the limit of $$\frac{(xy)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x^2+y^2)}
$$, how how would you do that? @user

Comment: @Vefhug For this last part your way is fine, my suggestion is only to discuss also the case with $x=0$.

Comment: Well, if $x=0$, then the numerator is identically $0$, so... the limit is $0$, right? @user

Comment: @Vefhug Yes of course! Your discussion is fine, you just need to consider that case to complete the proof.

Comment: @Vefhug As an alternative by AM-GM we can use $$|xy| \le \frac{x^2+y^2}{2} \implies x^2y^2 \le  \frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{4} $$

Comment: Clear, I like also this way :) Just one last thing before mark your answer as accepted:  why do I have to discuss the case $x=0$? Because of the bound with $\frac{x^2}{|x|}$, right?

Comment: @Vefhug Yes, this inequality is fine for $x\neq 0$.